WPF Application exits without saving data despite no exceptions thrown
I have a WPF application using MahApps.Metro with a title bar closure button to close the application. My goal is to store records in an Azure Storage Account when the application closes. I've implemented logic to save the data to Azure Storage within the window closing event handler. However, I've noticed that the application exits without saving the data, and no exceptions are being thrown. I've ensured that the event handler is properly subscribed to and that there are no errors during the saving process. What steps should I take to diagnose and resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated.
 public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
 {
     connString ="azure storage account key";
     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
     }
     
     private async void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
          await DataService.SaveData(connString, userId);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      
          throw new Exception($"An error occurred while saving userId: {ex.Message}");
      }
    
    } 
}

DataService :

TableClient connClient = new TableClient(connString, MytableName);
await connClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync() // Application closing here without any error


Have you inspected the result that was returned from CreateIfNotExistsAsync?

So you try to catch an exception, if there is one you immediately create and throw a new one (best practice is to at least include the original exception). Anway, that new exception isn't caught anywhere is it? So what is your expectation?

The problem is "async void"... This hack works well in case of simple button click but here.... Here main thread should wait for execution inside your method but it returns when code hits await and close the process

... So what I would try is two stage closing... First time you cancel the closing if some flag(if is set you just returns) is not set then after await you set the flag and call Close

I would advise a save button rather than implicit save on exit. You can debug through what's happening. You can show the user they successfully saved or tell them it failed and log an error.

Handling code in a closing event is a little bit tricky but not impossible.
You can use a flag to store the closing state, execute your own code and after that force closing the window.
private bool forceClose = false;

private void CloseForced()
{
    // Closing main window
    this.forceClose = true;
    this.Close();
}

private async void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  // force method to abort - we'll force a close explicitly
  e.Cancel = true;

  if (this.forceClose)
  {
    // cleanup code already ran - shut down
    e.Cancel = false;
    return;
  }

  // execute shutdown logic
  try
  {
    await DataService.SaveData(connString, userId);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception($"An error occurred while saving userId: {ex.Message}");
    return;
  }

  // explicitly force the window to close
  this.CloseForced();
}

Hope that helps.
